# How can I store specific column of database result?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem. I am trying to get a single row from my database. I have done that with an API like this:

```
function getUserData() {
    let returnData = "";

    MyApplication.API.queryDatabase("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Id = ?", 1).done(function(data) {
        returnData = data;
    }).fail(function(reason) {
        console.log(reason);
    });
    
    return returnData;
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
let userData = getUserData();
```

Now this results me in the following:
0:
Lastname: "Justme"
Email: "just.a.test@email.com"
Gender: "Male"
Id: 1
Origin: "Nederland"
Phonenumber: "0612345678"
Firstname: "Alexander"

Now I am trying to store a single value in a variable, but when I print it, it prints:

> undefined

While trying this code:

```
let userFirstname = userData.Firstname;
console.log(userFirstname);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What does it look like when you log userData? Are the two variables in the same scope?

Comment: No, I am trying to return the data from the query and store it in a variable called `userData`. When I log `userData` I see an empty row, but when I log it inside the API call, it is filled. This means that `data` is filled in the query, but when I set `returnData = data` it doesn't get set. Any ideas???